# Mobile data usage

Tags: iphone, ios5

I was wondering if it was possible to be able to check the amount of mobile data usage on the device and to remotly(from an app) reset those statistics.
Thank you.

Comment: To accept an answer as the most helpful, click the ✔ next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Apple is very strict about apps accessing statistics, data and other apps' data.

Edit: it seems there is a way after all, see @Aalok's comment.

Comment: This is not true just see [this](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

not at all possible through public APIs which means if you could use private APIs to fetch the data usage, you will not be able to submit the app to Appstore..

Comment: This is not true because see [this](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8). This application is on iTunes and also shows data usage for wi-fi and aslo for cellular.